# It always moved to a different section id

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

so I just make my first project and I have a problem I'm facing right now
so when I press the button it's supposed to go to 'belum selesai dibaca' or id="incompleteBookshelfList"
but its always showing in the 'Selesai dibaca' or id="completeBookshelfList"
anyone know what should I do because I've been tinkering with it for a few days and have not found the correct way yet

this is the repository
https://gitfront.io/r/user-2883908/RJRPjrov1UfT/Front-end-submission/

I think the problem I'm facing is in the javascript files in the makeBook function but I still don't know the correct way to solve it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bookshelf Apps</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <style>
    * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, input, button {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.head_bar {
    padding: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
}

main {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px;

}

.input_section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.input_section > h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.input_section > form > .input {
    margin: 8px 0;
}

.input_section > form > button {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input_section > form > button > span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.input_section > form > .input > input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.input_section > form > .input > label {
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.input_section > form > .input_inline {
    margin: 12px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.input_section > form > .input_inline > label {
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.search_section {
    margin: 16px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.search_section > h2 {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.search_section > form {
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 0.5fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.search_section > form > label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.search_section > form > input {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.search_section > form > button {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book_shelf {
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.book_shelf > h2 {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list {
    padding: 16px;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list > .book_item {
    padding: 8px 16px 16px 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list > .book_item > h3, p {
    margin: 8px 0;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list > .book_item > .action > button {
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list > .book_item > .action > .green {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;
}

.book_shelf > .book_list > .book_item > .action > .red {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
}

.check-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    background: url('../assets/check-outline.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.check-button:hover {
    background: url('../assets/check-solid.svg');
    background-size: contain;
}

.trash-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    background: url('../assets/trash-outline.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.trash-button:hover {
    background: url('../assets/trash-fill.svg');
    background-size: contain;
}

.undo-button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    background: url('../assets/undo-ouline.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}

.undo-button:hover {
    background: url('../assets/undo-ouline.svg');
    background-size: contain;
}

.check-button:focus, .trash-button {
    outline: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .wrapper {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper .container {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list-item {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .form {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="head_bar">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="head_bar__title">Bookshelf Apps</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
      <section class="input_section">
        <h2>Masukkan Buku Baru</h2>
        <form id="inputBook">
          <div class="input">
            <label for="inputBookTitle">Judul</label>
            <input id="inputBookTitle" type="text" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <label for="inputBookAuthor">Penulis</label>
            <input id="inputBookAuthor" type="text" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <label for="inputBookYear">Tahun</label>
            <input id="inputBookYear" type="number" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input_inline">
            <label for="inputBookIsComplete">Selesai dibaca</label>
            <input id="inputBookIsComplete" type="checkbox">
          </div>
          <button id="bookSubmit" type="submit">Masukkan Buku ke rak <span>Belum selesai dibaca</span></button>
        </form>
      </section>
      
      <section class="search_section">
        <h2>Cari Buku (Opsional)</h2>
        <form id="searchBook">
          <label for="searchBookTitle">Judul</label>
          <input id="searchBookTitle" type="text">
          <button id="searchSubmit" type="submit">Cari</button>
        </form>
      </section>
      
      <section class="book_shelf">
        <h2>Belum selesai dibaca</h2>
        
        <div id="incompleteBookshelfList" class="book_list">
    <!--      <article class="book_item">-->
    <!--        <h3>Book Title</h3>-->
    <!--        <p>Penulis: John Doe</p>-->
    <!--        <p>Tahun: 2002</p>-->
    <!--    -->
    <!--        <div class="action">-->
    <!--          <button class="green">Selesai dibaca</button>-->
    <!--          <button class="red">Hapus buku</button>-->
    <!--        </div>-->
    <!--      </article>-->
        </div>
      </section>
      
      <section class="book_shelf">
        <h2>Selesai dibaca</h2>
        
        <div id="completeBookshelfList" class="book_list">
    <!--      <article class="book_item">-->
    <!--        <h3>Book Title</h3>-->
    <!--        <p>Penulis: John Doe</p>-->
    <!--        <p>Tahun: 2002</p>-->
    <!--        -->
    <!--        <div class="action">-->
    <!--          <button class="green">Belum selesai di Baca</button>-->
    <!--          <button class="red">Hapus buku</button>-->
    <!--        </div>-->
    <!--      </article>-->
        </div>
      </section>
      </div>
    </main>
    
    <script>
    const books = [];
const RENDER_EVENT = 'render-book';



document.addEventListener(RENDER_EVENT, function () {
    const uncompletedBOOKList = document.getElementById('incompleteBookshelfList');
    uncompletedBOOKList.innerHTML = '';
   
    const completedBOOKList = document.getElementById('completeBookshelfList');
    completedBOOKList.innerHTML = '';
   
    for (const bookItem of books) {
      const bookElement = makeBook(bookItem);
      if (!bookItem.isCompleted)
        uncompletedBOOKList.append(bookElement);
      else
        completedBOOKList.append(bookElement);
    }
  });

function generateId() {
    return +new Date();
}

function generateBookObject(id, title, author, year, isCompleted) {
    return {
      id,
      title,
      author,
      year,
      isCompleted
    }
}

function clearForm() {
  const bookTitle = document.getElementById("inputBookTitle");
  const bookAuthor = document.getElementById("inputBookAuthor");
  const bookYear = document.getElementById("inputBookYear");
  const isCompleted = document.getElementById("inputBookIsComplete");

  bookTitle.value = "";
  bookAuthor.value = "";
  bookAuthor.value = "";
  bookYear.value = "";
  isCompleted.value = false;
}

function addBook() {
    const bookTitle = document.getElementById('inputBookTitle').value;
    const bookAuthor= document.getElementById('inputBookAuthor').value;
    const bookYear = document.getElementById('inputBookYear').value;
    const IsCompleted = document.getElementById('inputBookIsComplete').value;

    const generatedID = generateId();
    const bookObject = generateBookObject(
    generatedID,
    bookTitle,
    bookAuthor,
    bookYear, 
    IsCompleted);
    books.push(bookObject);
   
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event(RENDER_EVENT));
    saveData();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const submitForm = document.getElementById('inputBook');
    submitForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addBook();
      clearForm();
    });
    if (isStorageExist()) {
      loadDataFromStorage();
    }
});

function makeBook(bookObject) {
    const textTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    textTitle.innerText = bookObject.title;
   
    const textAuthor = document.createElement('p');
    textAuthor.innerText = bookObject.author;

    const textYear = document.createElement('p');
    textYear.innerText = bookObject.year;
   
    const textContainer = document.createElement('div');
    textContainer.classList.add('book_item');
    textContainer.append(textTitle, textAuthor, textYear);

    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('item', 'shadow');
    container.append(textContainer);
    container.setAttribute('id', `book-${bookObject.id}`);
    
   
    if (bookObject.isCompleted) {
        const undoButton = document.createElement('button');
        undoButton.classList.add('undo-button');
     
        undoButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          undoBookFromCompleted(bookObject.id);
        });
     
        const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
        trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
     
        trashButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          removeBookFromCompleted(bookObject.id);
        });
     
        container.append(undoButton, trashButton);
      } else {
        const checkButton = document.createElement('button');
        checkButton.classList.add('check-button');
        
        checkButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
          addBookToCompleted(bookObject.id);
        });
        
        container.append(checkButton);
      }
    return container;
  }






function addBookToCompleted (bookId) {
    const bookTarget = findBook(bookId);
   
    if (bookTarget == null) return;
   
    bookTarget.isCompleted = true;
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event(RENDER_EVENT));
    saveData();
}

function findBook(bookId) {
    for (const bookItem of books) {
      if (bookItem.id === bookId) {
        return bookItem;
      }
    }
    return null;
}
  
function removeBookFromCompleted(bookId) {
    const bookTarget = findBookIndex(bookId);
   
    if (bookTarget === -1) return;
   
    books.splice(bookTarget, 1);
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event(RENDER_EVENT));
    saveData();
}
   
   
function undoBookFromCompleted(bookId) {
    const bookTarget = findBook(bookId);
   
    if (bookTarget == null) return;
   
    bookTarget.isCompleted = false;
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event(RENDER_EVENT));
    saveData();
}

function findBookIndex(bookId) {
    for (const index in books) {
      if (books[index].id === bookId) {
        return index;
      }
    }
   
    return -1;
}

function saveData() {
  if (isStorageExist()) {
    const parsed = JSON.stringify(books);
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, parsed);
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event(SAVED_EVENT));
  }
}

const SAVED_EVENT = 'books';
const STORAGE_KEY = 'BOOK_APPS';
 
function isStorageExist(){
  if (typeof (Storage) === undefined) {
    alert('Browser kamu tidak mendukung local storage');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

document.addEventListener(SAVED_EVENT, function () {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
});
   
function loadDataFromStorage() {
  const serializedData = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
  let data = JSON.parse(serializedData);
 
  if (data !== null) {
    for (const book of data) {
      books.push(book);
    }
  }
 
  document.dispatchEvent(new Event(RENDER_EVENT));
  
  document.addEventListener(SAVED_EVENT, function () {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
  })
}
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

that's the complete snippet

Comment: Please don't link to a repo. Instead use the snippet editor on this page to create an example we can run and debug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your value for `IsCompleted` is not changing and you have defined it as a constant as well which means it will not change. there are few things you can do and it will run fine, initialise these variable with `var`

```
    var bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookYear, IsCompleted;
```

and change this line as well, you can do it inside the function as well.
this  `const IsCompleted = document.getElementById('inputBookIsComplete').value;`

to  `var IsCompleted = document.getElementById('inputBookIsComplete').checked;`

Comment: but if i do that how do I make then function the 'Selesai dibaca' checkbox, so when I check it it'll go to 'Selesai dibaca' section?

Comment: ihave edited the my answer you can check it will work now

Comment: now you dont need to define variables outside now

Comment: If a variable is defined as **const** and it's a primitive (number, boolean etc.), it not possible to change the value. Use **let** instead. Using **var** could lead to some magic issues, in case you don't know, how the **var** works.

Comment: magic happens when you reinitialize the variable defined as `var` but `let` dont let you re-initialze but you can re-assign